# Boundedness and derivative of $g(x)=x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$ (and $g(0)=0$)

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider the function $g$ defined by

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
      0 & x=0 \\
      x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) &  x \in [-\pi,0) \cup (0,\pi]  
\end{cases}
$$

How do I show that the function is bounded? And also how do I show if $g'(x)$ is continuous at $0$?

Comment: For boundedness, show there is an $M \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\left|x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right| \leq M$ for all $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$. Hint, $\left|x^2\cos\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right| \leq x^2$

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that $g'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{x^2\cos\frac{1}{x^2}-0}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}x\cos\frac{1}{x^2}=0$ and for $x\not=0$ $g'(x)=2x\cos\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}\ sin\frac{1}{x^2}$.

Because $\lim_{x\to o}g'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0}(2x\cos\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{2}{x}\sin\frac{1}{x^2})$ does not exist so $g'$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Squeeze theorem and the fact that $|g(x)| \leq x^2$, we have $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=0=f(0)$.  So $g(x)$ is continuous, and boundedness follows since $[-\pi,\pi]$ is compact.